# JTextArea setText oder Append doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to add a text to my jTextArea but it doesnt work. I created a method to fill in the text, but this doesnt work too.

Code from ConsoleFrame.java:

```
public void addLine(String line) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getTextArea().append(line + "\n");
        }
    });
    System.err.println("done");
}
```

Thats how I use this method (App.java):

```
public App() {
    initComponents();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe");
    fill();
    console.setVisible(true);
    console.addLine("Test");
}
```

Thats how my JFrame looks:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAxek.png)

Comment: Call the add method directly from addLine

Comment: Well, then change getTextArea by the name of your JTextArea

Answer (score 1):

Change getTextArea by the name of your JTextArea

Your code works, I just had to replace getTextArea with jtextarea1

```
 public void addLine(String line) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            jTextArea1.append(line + "\n");
        }
    });
    System.err.println("done");
}
```

Comment: doesnt work :((

Comment: @NickMueller: you've got problems in code not shown, and we can't help until you show it. Please consider creating and posting a decent [mcve] which would help us greatly in identifying your error. My guess is that you're updating the wrong object's state, but who knows?